# custom progress dialog not hiding

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I'm trying to show custom progressbar using [this](https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView) 3rd party library in 2 fragments of TabLayout. I'm displaying the progressbar while in background I'm doing volley stringrequest. Problem is the progressbar is not hiding even after the result gets loaded from web service. This problem does not occurs when I use regular progressdialog with TabLayout. Although this custom progressbar works fine in normal layout, its not working in TabLayout. Is there any particular reason for this? Thanks.

```js
// custom_progress_layout.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:indicator="BallClipRotatePulse"
        app:indicator_color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```css
// One of the fragment of TabLayout

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView tv1;
    private CShowProgress cShowProgress;
    private static final String CUSTOMERS_INFO = "My API";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        cShowProgress = CShowProgress.getInstance();

        showCustomersDetails();
    }

    private void showCustomersDetails() {

        cShowProgress.showProgress(getActivity());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CUSTOMERS_INFO,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        cShowProgress.hideProgress();  // THIS DOESNOT WORK AS PROGRESSBAR STILL SHOWS

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("aboutuser");

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String str1 = "Contact:" + obj.getString("primary_contact");
                                String str2 = "EMail:" + obj.getString("email");
                               String total = str1 + "\n" + str2;
                                tv1.setText(total);
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("spaid", "145");
                params.put("customer_id", "64");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }



}
```

```html
//Custom Class for 3rd party library of progressbar

public class CShowProgress {
    public static CShowProgress s_m_oCShowProgress;
    public static Context m_Context;
    public Dialog m_Dialog;

    public CShowProgress(Context m_Context) {
        this.m_Context = m_Context;
    }

    public static CShowProgress getInstance() {
        if (s_m_oCShowProgress == null) {
            s_m_oCShowProgress = new CShowProgress(m_Context);
        }
        return s_m_oCShowProgress;
    }

    public void showProgress(Context m_Context) {
        m_Dialog = new Dialog(m_Context);
        m_Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        m_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_layout);
        m_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        m_Dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        m_Dialog.setCancelable(true);
        m_Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        m_Dialog.show();
    }

    public void hideProgress() {
        if (m_Dialog != null) {
            m_Dialog.dismiss();
            m_Dialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also get this issue. Anyone have any solutions..?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  public void hideProgress() {
    if (m_Dialog != null) {
        m_Dialog.setVisible(View.GONE);
        m_Dialog = null;
    }
}
```

OR in your `onResponse()`

```
 cShowProgress.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Still not working. Here the problem is the library is for progressbar (whose visibility can be made gone) but the custom class is for ProgressDialog with custom layout (whose visibility cannot be made gone).

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in my custom progress dialog class and now it works...

```html
public class CShowProgress extends Dialog{
    private Dialog mpd = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CShowProgress(Context context) {
        super(context)
    }

    

    public void showProgress(Context context) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_progress_layout, null);

        mpd = new Dialog(context);
        mpd.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mpd.setContentView(view);
        mpd.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mpd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        mpd.setCancelable(true);
        mpd.show();
    }

    public void hideProgress() {
        if (mpd != null) {
            if (mpd.isShowing()){
                mpd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```